# How to create and modify .doc and .docx file in Qt?

Tags: qt, doc

I want to create and modify .doc and .docx file in Qt creator with ability to compile for Windows, Linux, Android and IOS.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Qt-specific question imho. Anyhow here is my answer:

Quoting wikipedia:

> is a zipped, XML-based file format

What this means is you need to decompress (you need to figure out how it is compressed to begin with) and process the XML for `doc` files. Qt provides basic (de)compression facilities and does provide the tools to process XML data.

In terms of Qt Creator - you have to write your own plugin for that purpose. You can check what's already there - processing of CMake, C++, C, Python files.

You should use what's already there. LibreOffice for example, which is open source and free, can handle such documents (incl. `doc`). There are libraries that do that too. So your best bet is to integrate some library into your Qt application. I would NOT recommend implementing it yourself unless you have a lot of spare time. The fact that big projects such as LibreOffice, OpenOffice etc. still don't have 100% support for such documents should give a big enough hint that it's not a trivial task.